# CSS Floats And Dynamic Content

Tags: css, css-float, dynamic-content

I have a page which has a nav bar at the top.  Within the nav bar there are 2 sets of menus (ul).  One set is float left, the other float right.  Then below the entire menu, is the content, which is in the the flow.

The problem is, the Nav menus are going to have dynamic content.  So they need to:

- push the content down as they grow
- can't have a fixed height.

Any way to accomplish this, but the "effect" of the menus floated on opposite side of the page?

Comment: Is there anything you can show us to help clarify? Maybe you already have half of it done? If not, drawing a picture might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `overflow: auto;` to the DIV or whatever container element is around the two nav UL's.

```
#header { overflow: auto; }

<div id="header">
 <ul id="primaryNav">...</ul>
 <ul id="secondaryNav">...</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">...</div>
```

Comment: +1 because it is the right approach but some browsers also need to have a `width` specified to clear the floats properly. found here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this css and give the parent of those ULs (the nav bar) class `clearfix`. This way you dont have to specify a fixed height and they will push the content down.

The CSS you need:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```